# How to make a object follow the direction of the PointerLockControls in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using `Three.js` and `PointerLockControls` to create simple FPS game. What I am trying to do is to attach a weapon to the camera/controls.

I was able to position the gun in front of the camera and move it along on the x/y axis, but it does not move along the z axis (up/down).

```
function updateGun() {
    if (weapon) {
        const yaw = controls.getObject();
        weapon.position.set(
            yaw.position.x - Math.sin(yaw.rotation.y) * 3,
            yaw.position.y - 1,
            yaw.position.z - Math.cos(yaw.rotation.y) * 3);

        weapon.rotation.set(
            yaw.rotation.x,
            (yaw.rotation.y - Math.PI),
            yaw.rotation.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `PointerLockControls` and want to add an object that remains in front of the camera, you can use this pattern:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 16, 8 ), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
mesh.position.z = - 100; // some negative number

camera.add( mesh );
```

If you are not using `PointerLockControls`, you can still use the same technique, you just have to be sure to add the camera as a child of the scene.

```
scene.add( camera );
camera.add( mesh );
```

three.js r.84